# Selecting calculation based o which textfield is left blank

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am trying to make a code (in Swift 4 xcode 9) that uses 3 variables, 2 of which are given by the user via textfields. The value of the other variable will be calculated based on which variable was left blank. For example, if the user leaves textfield1 blank, the inputs from the textfield2 and textfield3 will be used on calculations when a button is pressed. If the user leaves the textfield2 blank, the inputs of textfield1 and textfield3 are used and so on... I also set the delegates, convert the UITextField into float, etc.

I am trying to create a selector based on which textfield is left blank, but without success...

Thanks in advance!

```
//instance variables to hold values entered by the user
var one : Float = 0
var two : Float = 0
var three : Float = 0

//TextFields variables
@IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField3: UITextField!

func calculate() {
    var result : Float = 0

    // *** Selector ***

    //if user leaves textfield1 blank
    if (textField1.text?.isEqual(nil))! {
        result = textField2 * textfield3
        resultLabel.text = "\(result)"
        }

    //if user leaves textField2 blank
    else if (textField2.text?.isEqual(nil))! {
        result = textfield1 / textField3
        resultLabel.text = "\(result)"
            }

    //if user leaves textField3 blank
    else if (textfield3.text?.isEqual(nil))! {

        result = textfield1 + textfield2
        resultLabel.text = "\(result)"
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is quite manually, not a recommended way. Swift supports a lot of transformation functions for doing such work.

First create an array to store your textfields:

```
var inputs: [UITextField] = [UITextField]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    inputs.append(textField1)
    inputs.append(textField2)
    inputs.append(textField3)
}
```

Now you have an array of all inputs. Our work now is to transform the inputs and get the result value:

```
func calculation() {
    var blankIndex = 0 // keep track of which input is blank

    // let transform our inputs into float values
    let values = inputs.enumerated()
        .map { (i, textField) -> Float? in
            if let text = textField.text, !text.isEmpty {
                blankIndex = i // we know which input is blank
                return Float(text)!
            }
            return nil
        }
        .filter { $0 != nil }
        .map { $0! }

    // now we need to validate out inputs
    // only one input is left blank by the user
    if values.count != 2 {
        // show alert for notifying user about this

        // stop our calculation
        return
    }

    // now our values contain only valid inputs the we need,
    // we can start do our calculation now
    let result: Float
    switch blankIndex {
    case 0: result = values[0] * values[1]
    case 1: result = values[0] / values[1]
    default: result = values[0] + values[1]
    }
}
```

At this point, result variable is the result that you need

Comment: The array "inputs" always has three elements (the variables), but array "values" only shows two elements, so when the code perform the calculations gives an "out of bounds" crash.
For validation, i am using          
    var isValid = true
    for textField in inputs {
        if textField.isEqual("") {
            isValid = false
            }
            else {
                isValid = true
            }
        }

Comment: My code is assumed that your requirement (only one input is left blank) is validated. Therefore it could cause index out of range exception. Please my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to perform math operation on `UITextField`s which are obviously not possible. Text fields contain strings. You want to do math on the `Float`s represented by those strings.

If you generalize your prohblem a bit, it essentially boils down to:

- Find out which of the three fields is empty (only 1 is allowed to be so)
- Convert the string values of the other 2 fields to `Float`s
- Perform a math operation on these 2 `Float`s and ouptut a result to a label

Code:

```
func calculate() {
    // These are the possible operations that you will perform
    // Each is a closure that takes 2 Floats and return a Float
    let plus     = { (lhs: Float, rhs: Float) in lhs + rhs }
    let multiply = { (lhs: Float, rhs: Float) in lhs * rhs }
    let divide   = { (lhs: Float, rhs: Float) in lhs / rhs }

    var lhsStr = ""         // the string stored in the first non-empty text field
    var rhsStr = ""         // the string stored in the second non-empty text field
    var operation = plus    // don't worry about the default. We will change this later

    // Find which field is empty
    // We allow only one of the fields to be empty, not 0, 2, or 3.
    switch (textField1.text!.isEmpty, textField2.text!.isEmpty, textField3.text!.isEmpty) {
    case (true, false, false):
        lhsStr = textField2.text!
        rhsStr = textField3.text!
        operation = multiply
    case (false, true, false):
        lhsStr = textField1.text!
        rhsStr = textField3.text!
        operation = divide
    case (false, false, true):
        lhsStr = textField1.text!
        rhsStr = textField2.text!
        operation = plus
    default:
        fatalError("One and only one of the fields must be empty")
    }

    // Now convert the 2 Strings to Floats
    if let lhs = Float(lhsStr), let rhs = Float(rhsStr) {
        let result = operation(lhs, rhs)
        resultLabel.text = "\(result)"
    } else {
        fatalError("Cannot convert string to number")
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Why is `sender` declared as `NSObject`? This is Swift. Declare it as the specific object type (UIButton, etc.) or at least `Any`. 2. Why `Float` and not `Double`? 3. `UITextField text` won't return `nil`. It's always safe to force-unwrap. `let isField1Empty = textField1.text!.isEmpty`

Comment: 1. That's a typo. 2. OP used `Float` so I just assume that. 3. `UIKit` won't assign `nil` to `UITextField.text` but what about user code? The property is optional so assigning a `nil` to it is perfectly valid.

Comment: iOS 10 or later you can use `UIKeyInput` property `hasText` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyinput/1614457-hastext

Comment: 3. If you assign `nil` to a text field's `text` property and then immediately read it back, you get an empty string, not nil. As I said, it's always safe to force-unwrap the `text` property of a `UITextField`. It's documented. Try it.

Comment: btw `textField1.text?.isEmpty ?? true` is wrong it should be `textField1.text?.isEmpty == true` or simply `textField1.text!.isEmpty` considering that the text property will never return nil its default value is an empty string

Comment: @rmaddy I didn't know that

Comment: If you are coding for iOS10 or later better to use `textField1.hasText`.